# Download GIMP and view the source code on a Mac

Tags: mac, gimp, source-code

I would like to download [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) (the open source graphics application) onto my Mac. I don't want to run GIMP but rather view the source code. I have a vague understanding of tar balls (.tar.bz2) and don't know how to extract the code from the file.

Is there a simple command that I can just type into the terminal to get the source? A step-by-step guide would be helpful too.

Thanks.

Comment: my favorite (i have no idea why i prefer it over the much simpler tar xjvf gimp.tar.gz tho): bzip2 -cd gimp.tar.gz | tar xvf -

Comment: Download the file, and double click on it. OS X knows how to handle tar files.

Comment: You might be interested in Seashore, homepage - http://seashore.sourceforge.net/The_Seashore_Project/About.html source - http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=71670

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
curl ftp://ftp.gimp.org/pub/gimp/v2.6/gimp-2.6.11.tar.bz2 --O gimp-2.6.11.tar.bz2
tar -jxvf gimp-2.6.11.tar.bz2
```

The first line (`curl ...`) downloads the latest source tar ball from gimp's servers to the local directory.
The second line (`tar ...`) extracts the files. The flags passed to `tar` are `j`,`x`,`v`, and `f` and then the file to extract.

- The `j` flag tells tar to extract a
  bzip2 compressed file.
- The `x` flag tells tar to be in extract mode.
- The `v` flag tells tar to be 'verbose' (i.e. tell you what it's doing)
- The `f` flag is what is receiving the filename as its parameter.

Comment: No `wget` on a default Mac install. Try `curl`.

Comment: @Thilo: Thanks, didn't realize that, I think wget was one of the first things I installed from ports when I got a Mac.

Comment: @Reese: Fantastic, that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Did you not see the download section? They show you the FTP details right there for the source files. I'm confused how 'easy' you want this?

Compiling from source is not easier than an installer...

http://www.gimp.org/downloads/

To extract a `tar.bz2`:

```
tar -jxvf gimp-2.6.11.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just double-click any `.tar.bz2` file on Mac OS X. It will decompress and then untar in the same directory.

Comment: and on the command line, just use `open` instead of `tar <options>`.

Comment: I initially tried double clicking the first time and it didn't work, so I went back and tried it again and it worked. Really weird. Thanks.